# what are the consequences of turning off connection pooling?

Tags: connection, odbc, driver, pooling

I have a main application using an ODBC driver and connection pooling.  A separate program also accesses the connection pools via the same driver but an issue has been detected with the connection pool and driver by this 2nd program.

If we turn off connection pooling it works fine.

What are the consequences for the main application if I turn off connection pooling and could we / should we be turning it off and on whilst this 2nd program runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to state the obvious but if you disable the connection pool then applications connecting and disconnecting repeatedly will not use a pooled connection and will have to connect afresh each time. This may mean the application which was benefiting from the pool is a little slower but it depends on a lot of factors e.g., the default pool timeout is 60s so if you were connecting only once every 2 minutes you weren't using pooled connections anyway.

Comment: Thanks - I figured it would be a timing issue but wasn't sure if there would be anything else affected.